# How to Export CSV file in lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

How to Export CSV file in lumen laravel with package
create an API for export csv & excel file using lumen laravel

Comment: check this https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel

Comment: Are you looking to respond with a csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use native PHP's method for exporting csv (fputcsv).
Note that `$csvData` variable must be an array. For example:

[
    [
    1,2,3
    ],
    [
    4,5,6
    ] ]

After exporting it csv will look like:

1,2,3

4,5,6

```
$csv = fopen('/home/user/Desktop/test.csv', 'w');

foreach ($csvData as $row){
    fputcsv($csv, $row);
}

fclose($csv);
```

Comment: Yes, You are right but how can I do with the package in Lumen?

Comment: https://laravel-excel.com This is some Laravel package for working with excel/csv files (Export/Import and other stuff), but i am not sure if it will work with Lumen.